# AngularJS - ng-include lost scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a little application on my own with angular and projected this like a state machine, so something must be done to change the state. By changing the state I mean include other .html file. I using ng-include which lost parent scope in directive. I read topics about it before, but nothing helps me. I know, that scope is created as child if I do it by ng-include, but I need my parent scope, to make scope.$emit(...) and really don't know what now...

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="rpsApp">
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
  <base href="/">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webroot/css/default.css"/>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="webroot/js/main.js"></script>
  
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main" ng-controller="rpsController as rpsc">
   <ng-include src="data.stateData.template.file"></ng-include>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```js
angular.module('rpsApp', []).
service('rpsManager', function(){
 
 var currentState;
 var isInit = true;
 
 return {
   getState: function(){
    return currentState;
   },
   setState: function(stateValue){
    console.log('set state '+stateValue);
    if (stateValue > 0) {
     currentState = stateValue;
    }
   },
   getInit: function(){
    return isInit;
   }, 
   setInit: function(initValue){
    if (initValue != 'undefined') {
     isInit = initValue;
    }
   }
 };
 
}).
controller('rpsController', function($scope, rpsManager) {
 
 var templatePath = 'templates/';
 $scope.data = {};
 
 $scope.data.templates = [
  {file: templatePath+'intro.tpl'},
  {file: templatePath+'select-item.tpl'},
  {file: templatePath+'select-enemy.tpl'},
  {file: templatePath+'select-player.tpl'},
  {file: templatePath+'game-container.tpl'},
  {file: templatePath+'game-results.tpl'}
 ];
 
 $scope.data.states = [
  {stateNo: 1, name: 'Intro', template: $scope.data.templates[0]},
  {stateNo: 2, name: 'Type name', template: $scope.data.templates[1]},
  {stateNo: 3, name: 'Select game item', template: $scope.data.templates[1]},
  {stateNo: 4, name: 'Select enemy', template: $scope.data.templates[2]},
  {stateNo: 5, name: 'Select online player', template: $scope.data.templates[3]},
  {stateNo: 6, name: 'Waiting for player / computer', template: $scope.data.templates[4]},
  {stateNo: 7, name: 'Game result', template: $scope.data.templates[4]},
  {stateNo: 8, name: 'View your all game results', template: $scope.data.templates[5]},
 ];
 
 $scope.$on('stateChange', function(e, data){
  
  console.log('state change');
  rpsManager.setState(data);
  $scope.data.stateData = _stateSelect(data);
  
 });
 
 if (rpsManager.getInit() == true) {
  
  $scope.$emit('stateChange', 1);
  rpsManager.setInit(false);
 }
 
 function _stateSelect(stateNo) {
  
  var _stateObj = false;
  
  if (stateNo > 0) {
   for (a=0; a<$scope.data.states.length; a++) {
    if ($scope.data.states[a].stateNo == stateNo) {
     _stateObj = $scope.data.states[a];
    }
   }
  }
  return _stateObj;
 }
 
}).
directive('rpsIntro', function(){
 console.log('directive online');
 return {
  scope: true,
  transclude: false, 
  link: function(scope, element, attrs){
   console.log('inside link');
   TweenMax.staggerTo(".letter", 1, {opacity:1}, 0.3);
   TweenMax.to(".word", 1, {opacity:1, onComplete: function(){
    
    scope.$emit('stateChanged', 2);
    
   }}, 1.5).delay(2.4);
  }
 }
 
});
```